# SSMS Database Node Refresh causes Restore to Fail

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have confirmed via testing that clicking on the refresh icon (one or more times) for the database node of a SQL Server instance being observed in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS 2012) causes my 3rd-party database restore software to fail. If the refresh icon is not clicked, then the restore succeeds.

My question: what occurs in the SQL Server engine (or the msdb database) when the refresh icon is clicked?

Update (2:36pm)
When the failure occurs, one database is left in a restoring state. The specific error is "The database cannot be recovered because the log was not restored."

Update (2:48pm)
The 3rd-party database restore software is GUI-driven. A restore script is not available to post. I will capture the commands via Profiler.

Update (3:30pm) - restore script captured from Profiler (with no SSMS refresh)

```
select name, physical_name from model.sys.database_files
select name from master..sysdatabases where name = 'DC_EARTH001'
select DatabaseProperty( 'DC_EARTH001', 'IsInLoad' )
select database_id from master.sys.databases where name ='DC_EARTH001'
select DatabaseProperty( 'DC_EARTH001', 'IsSuspect' )
select DatabaseProperty( 'DC_EARTH001', 'IsShutdown' )
select name, physical_name from model.sys.database_files
RESTORE DATABASE [DC_EARTH001] FROM VIRTUAL_DEVICE='MVD_SQLAgent-DC_EARTH001__a6d9fb41_c3fc_4b00_a78e_596dd32fc149_' WITH SNAPSHOT, NORECOVERY, MOVE 'DC_EARTH001' TO 'X:\DC_EARTH001.mdf', MOVE 'DC_EARTH001_log' TO 'Y:\DC_EARTH001_log.ldf'

select name, physical_name from model.sys.database_files
select name from master..sysdatabases where name = 'DC_EARTH002'
select DatabaseProperty( 'DC_EARTH002', 'IsInLoad' )
select database_id from master.sys.databases where name ='DC_EARTH002'
select DatabaseProperty( 'DC_EARTH002', 'IsSuspect' )
select DatabaseProperty( 'DC_EARTH002', 'IsShutdown' )
RESTORE DATABASE [DC_EARTH002] FROM VIRTUAL_DEVICE='MVD_SQLAgent-DC_EARTH002__584bf879_215d_4c15_b7ad_230ecab60488_' WITH SNAPSHOT, NORECOVERY, MOVE 'DC_EARTH002' TO 'X:\DC_EARTH002.mdf', MOVE 'DC_EARTH002_log' TO 'Y:\DC_EARTH002_log.LDF'

select name from master..sysdatabases where name = 'DC_EARTH003'
select name, physical_name from model.sys.database_files
select DatabaseProperty( 'DC_EARTH003', 'IsInLoad' )
select database_id from master.sys.databases where name ='DC_EARTH003'
select DatabaseProperty( 'DC_EARTH003', 'IsSuspect' )
select DatabaseProperty( 'DC_EARTH003', 'IsShutdown' )
RESTORE DATABASE [DC_EARTH003] FROM virtual_device = 'DC_EARTH003_00__416c5ed9_54e9_4ad1_9adc_3c7401c3fd57_' WITH NORECOVERY , MOVE 'DC_EARTH003_data' TO 'X:\DC_EARTH003.mdf', MOVE 'DC_EARTH003_log' TO 'Y:\DC_EARTH003.ldf'

exec xp_msver
select convert( char(100), ServerProperty('Edition') )
select is_srvrolemember( 'sysadmin', 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM' )
exec sp_helpsort
select name, source_database_id from master.sys.databases order by name

select DatabaseProperty( 'DC_EARTH003', 'IsTruncLog' )
select status from sysdatabases where name='DC_EARTH003'
RESTORE DATABASE [DC_EARTH003] WITH RECOVERY

select DatabaseProperty( 'DC_EARTH001', 'IsTruncLog' )
select status from sysdatabases where name='DC_EARTH001'
RESTORE DATABASE [DC_EARTH001] WITH RECOVERY

select DatabaseProperty( 'DC_EARTH002', 'IsTruncLog' )
select status from sysdatabases where name='DC_EARTH002'
RESTORE DATABASE [DC_EARTH002] WITH RECOVERY
```

Update (2015/04/07 @ 9:25am)
Solution proposed by Microsoft: SQL Server 2012 SP1 CU1

- Slow performance or deadlock when you restore a database and execute statements at the same time in SQL Server 2012 (Scenario 2 http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2725950

Update (2015/04/07 @ 9:25am)
Solution implemented: SQL Server 2012 SP1 CU15 http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3038001

- The issue is resolved

Comment: Running a profiler reveals that it run [**this**](http://pastebin.com/kyB42MJD) sql in the background when you refresh the *databases* node in SSMS. I would doubt if that affects your restore. You should use 
`alter database db_name set single_user with rollback immediate;
 waitfor delay '00:00:05';
alter database db_name set multi_user with rollback immediate;`. This will kill all the connections to that particular database and then run your restore database script.

Comment: `The database cannot be recovered because the log was not restored.` This is a different error than what you meant. You have to use `WITH REPLACE` option when doing restore of a current database. Can you post your restore script ?

Comment: Are you trying to restore on existing databases ? In other words, do the DC_EARTH003, 001, 002 etc exist on the server that you are trying to restore ?

Comment: @Kin: the databases being restored do not exist on the target.

Comment: You have to re-restore the database. Drop the database that is left in restoring state. You may want to consult the 3rd party tool provider why the database is screwed up.

Comment: Thank you @Kin. You are correct; however, the original question stands unanswered: why does a database node refresh cause the restore to fail?

Comment: A refresh of the database node won't fail the restore, unless you have something that is holding up locks for longer duration. I have tried restoring a 10GB database and refreshing the node does not fail the restore. What version of SSMS you are using? Maybe you should use a newer version of SSMS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server 2012 SP1 CU15 (http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3038001) resolves the issue (no deadlock occurs as the result of issuing a command during a database restore).